# Controlling a 16x16 led dot matrix with pyfirmata

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, arduino, led

Well, what I'm trying to do, is be able to dynamically re-draw a 16x16 arduino compatible led dot matrix with python through pyfirmata. I can't seem to find a way to go about it...
What I want to know how to do, is convert a 16x16 matrix into the led matrix display using python.
- Here's an example of a scrolling clock I made in python using pyfirmata. (this example works on an 8x8 led dot matrix, not 16x16 which is what I want...

```
"""led_matrix.py"""

from time import sleep

from pyfirmata import Arduino

HIGH = 1
LOW = 0

dataIn = 2
load = 3
clock = 4
maxInUse = 1
Intensity = 3

max7219_reg_noop = 0x00
max7219_reg_digit0 = 0x01
max7219_reg_digit1 = 0x02
max7219_reg_digit2 = 0x03
max7219_reg_digit3 = 0x04
max7219_reg_digit4 = 0x05
max7219_reg_digit5 = 0x06
max7219_reg_digit6 = 0x07
max7219_reg_digit7 = 0x08
max7219_reg_decodeMode = 0x09
max7219_reg_intensity = 0x0a
max7219_reg_scanLimit = 0x0b
max7219_reg_shutdown = 0x0c
max7219_reg_displayTest = 0x0f

intensity = 0x01

class LedMatrix:
    def __init__(self, board, dataIn, load, clock, maxInUse=1):
        self._board = board

        self.pins = dict()
        self.pins['dataIn'] = dataIn
        self.pins['load'] = load
        self.pins['clock'] = clock
        self.maxInUse = maxInUse

    def _digitalWrite(self, pin, val):
        self._board.digital[pin].write(val)

    def _putByte(self, data):
        for i in range(8, 0, -1):
            mask = 0x01 << (i - 1)
            self._digitalWrite(self.pins["clock"], LOW)
            if data & mask:
                self._digitalWrite(self.pins["dataIn"], HIGH)
            else:
                self._digitalWrite(self.pins["dataIn"], LOW)
            self._digitalWrite(self.pins["clock"], HIGH)

    def maxSingle(self, reg, col):
        """ Change the row of lights at reg to read as binary of col. """
        self._digitalWrite(self.pins["load"], LOW)
        self._putByte(reg)
        self._putByte(col)
        self._digitalWrite(self.pins["load"], LOW)
        self._digitalWrite(self.pins["load"], HIGH)

    def maxAll(self, reg, col):
        """ Like calling maxSingle on every chained matrix """
        self._digitalWrite(self.pins["load"], LOW)
        for _ in range(0, self.maxInUse):
            self._putByte(reg)
            self._putByte(col)
        self._digitalWrite(self.pins["load"], LOW)
        self._digitalWrite(self.pins["load"], HIGH)

    def maxOne(self, maxNr, reg, col):
        """ Specify the matrix to be written to with maxNr. Then acts as maxSingle on that specific matrix. """
        self._digitalWrite(self.pins["load"], LOW)

        for _ in range(self.maxInUse, maxNr, -1):
            self._putByte(0)
            self._putByte(0)

        self._putByte(reg)
        self._putByte(col)

        for _ in range(maxNr - 1, 0, -1):
            self._putByte(0)
            self._putByte(0)

        self._digitalWrite(self.pins["load"], LOW)
        self._digitalWrite(self.pins["load"], HIGH)

    def clear(self):
        for e in range(1, 9):
            self.maxAll(e, 0)

    def draw_matrix(self, point_matrix):
        for col, pointlist in enumerate(point_matrix):
            self.maxSingle(col + 1, int(''.join(str(v) for v in pointlist), 2))

    def setup(self):
        print('Initializing _matrix...')
        self._digitalWrite(13, HIGH)
        self.maxAll(max7219_reg_scanLimit, 0x07)
        self.maxAll(max7219_reg_decodeMode, 0x00)
        self.maxAll(max7219_reg_shutdown, 0x01)
        self.maxAll(max7219_reg_displayTest, 0x00)
        self.clear()
        self.maxAll(max7219_reg_intensity, intensity & intensity)
        print('Done')

rotated = True

import numpy as np

def convertarray(array):

    m = np.array(array)
    m = np.rot90(m, 3)

    return m.tolist()

import datetime as date



import json

data = json.loads(open('jsonNums.json', 'r').read())

def getTime():
    n = date.datetime.now()
    hour = n.hour
    minute = n.minute
    second = n.second

    PM = False
    if hour > 12: hour -= 12; PM = True

    if len(str(hour)) < 2: hour = str( f"0{hour}" )
    hour=str(hour)

    if len(str(minute)) < 2: minute = str( f"0{minute}" )
    minute = str(minute)

    if len(str(second)) < 2: second = str( f"0{second}" )
    second = str(second)

    pm = "AM"
    if PM: pm = "PM"

    fullTime = f"{hour}:{minute}.{pm}"

    display = []
    for i in range(8):
        row = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        for char in fullTime:
            if char == "0":
                row.extend(data["0"][i])
            elif char == "1":
                row.extend(data["1"][i])
            elif char == "2":
                row.extend(data["2"][i])
            elif char == "3":
                row.extend(data["3"][i])
            elif char == "4":
                row.extend(data["4"][i])
            elif char == "5":
                row.extend(data["5"][i])
            elif char == "6":
                row.extend(data["6"][i])
            elif char == "7":
                row.extend(data["7"][i])
            elif char == "8":
                row.extend(data["8"][i])
            elif char == "9":
                row.extend(data["9"][i])

            elif char == ":":
                row.extend(data["COLON"][i])
            elif char == ".":
                row.extend(data["POINT"][i])

            elif char == "A":
                row.extend(data["AM"][i])
                break

            elif char == "P":
                row.extend(data["PM"][i])
                break

        row.extend([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

        display.append(row)

    return display




for row in (getTime()): print(row)

scrollMultiplier = 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    board = Arduino('COM1')
    matrix = LedMatrix(board, dataIn, load, clock)
    matrix.setup()
    print("Loop running")



    while True:

        # print("New iteration")
        displayx = getTime()
        # print("Time collected")

        r = int(len(displayx[0]) - 8)
        # print(f"Repeat = {r}")

        for i in range(0, r, scrollMultiplier): # Scrolling effect

            x=[]

            for XX in displayx:

                # print(f"XX = {XX}")

                r=[]
                nr = XX[i:i+8]

                # print(f"nr = {nr}")

                x.append(nr)

                # print("X.append(nr)")

            x = convertarray(x)

            matrix.draw_matrix(x)
```

I can't seem to find any help online, so that's why I asked here...
Any help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the stackoverflow.

As I can see from your code, there are a few variables controlling the number of cells of dot matrix display.

```
max7219_reg_digit{ 0-1 }

row = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

r = int(len(displayx[0]) - 8)

def _putByte(self, data):
    for i in range(8, 0, -1): 
        nr = XX[i:i+8]`
```

If I am guessing correctly, your library handles the job of converting decimals to an array of binary values. If thats the case, your job will be changing all variables related to the limit of having 8 cells to 16 cells.

Hope this helps, enjoy!